# current_page? wrong after POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm displaying certain items in my navigation bar depending on the current page. When I go to my sign in page the correct items are displayed. If I sign in with an incorrect password the items change and are incorrect.

In my html I check `if (current_page?(new_user_session_path))`

After the incorrect password is submitted and the page reloads this condition isn't returning true and it's displaying the wrong items in the navbar. I looked through the requests on the server logs and I'm guessing it's because the second time around the page loads after a POST (the unsuccessful password submission). Is there a different path I need to check for the second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Scott's answer, you could create a helper in **app/helpers/navigation_helper.rb** for instance, like so:

```
module NavigationHelper
    def current_location?(*args)
        options = args.extract_options!
        options.each do |key, val|
            return false unless eval("controller.#{key.to_s}_name") == val
        end
        true
    end
end
```

And use it this way:

```
current_location?(controller: 'my_controller', action: 'new')
current_location?(controller: 'my_controller')
current_location?(action: 'new')
```

In your view you can then do something like:

```
# Change this according what your really need
if current_location?(controller: 'sessions', action: 'new')
```

Hope it helps ; )

Comment: I'm determining the page through an if statement in my html. Where would I put this above code?

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected {, expecting '(' on the return false line.

Comment: Oops forgot `args.extract_options!` edited my answer again, sorry ; )

Comment: No, it didn't, I edited one last time, take this version instead. You're welcome by the way ; ) (it was always returning true, sorry for that)

Comment: It seems to be returning false every time now

Comment: Make sure you send the right controller and/or action names to the method. I tested it in my app and it works, so there must be something else...

Comment: My mistake, you were right, I was sending the wrong controller (devise/sessions instead of just sessions). Thanks fro your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source code of `current_page?`, it always returns false if the request's HTTP mode is anything other than GET or HEAD:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F

```
def current_page?(options)
  unless request
    raise "You cannot use helpers that need to determine the current "                  "page unless your view context provides a Request object "                  "in a #request method"
  end

  return false unless request.get? || request.head?

...
```

So even if your incorrect form is at exactly the same path as `new_user_session_path`, your logic won't match.

You may want to consider comparing `controller.controller_name` and `controller.action_name` directly instead. Not exactly elegant, but it's going to be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks! So in my if statement in the html would I use if controller.devise?

Comment: Figured it out current_page?(:controller => 'devise/sessions', :action => 'new) but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: In that case, you're still hitting the same issue – current_page? is returning false because the request is an HTTP POST rather than a GET or HEAD. @Sparda is showing you the right thing to do – work out the conditional comparisons you need to do, and extract them into a general purpose helper.

Comment: Thanks, I followed @Sparada's post. Thanks for your help.